# Adiabatic compression for an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics

I´m trying to solve the exercise 7.4-11 of Callen Thermodynamics 2nd edition.
Where a 2-mole ideal gas of pressure $10^5$ Pa and temperature of $273.15$ K (0° C) is adiabatically compressed to $573.15$ K (300° C). So we are asked for the final pressure (ANS: $P_f=15\times10^5$ Pa).
We also know that the molar heat capacity $c_p$ is a quadratic function of the temperature:
$$c_p=26.20+11.49\times 10^{-3}T-3.223\times 10^{-6}T^2$$

I was told that we can find the the final pressure can be found by integrating the equation:
$$dT=\dfrac{Tv\alpha}{c_p}dP$$
But i can´t see how.

Comment: Which part don't you see? How you can get it by integrating? Why you would integrate that equation? Where the equation comes from?

Comment: @tpg2114 
It comes by reducing the derivative: $dT=(\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial P})_{S, N} dP=\dfrac{Tv\alpha}{c_p}dP$.

Comment: Right -- so again, I'm trying to clarify what the difficulty is. You said "But I can't see how." If you know where the equation comes from, do you not see how to perform the integration? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, i know where it came from, but can´t relate to the problem

Comment: I'm no expert in thermodynamics in particular, but mathematically speaking, integrating that expression would allow you to solve for $P$ in terms of $T$. Then, knowing what $T_f$ is, you should be able to find $P_f$. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something here myself.

Comment: @Αδριανός You're correct -- this is just a straight forward integration problem. Move all the $T$'s the left side, integrate both sides (where $P_f$ is unknown) and solve the expression for $P_f$. Unless I'm also misunderstanding something here.

Comment: All right, but in the integrand, there is the molar volume, which i dont think is a constant because of the compression

Comment: @VictorFranciscoSalazarGarci And is there a relationship between $P$ and $\nu$? Perhaps one using the fact this is an ideal gas and the process is adiabatic?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's my understanding of the problem. To preface, let me know if I've misunderstood the concept; this is just the math of it.

$dT=\dfrac{Tv\alpha}{c_p}dP$

$c_p=26.20+11.49\times 10^{-3}T-3.223\times 10^{-6}T^2$

$\frac{26.20+11.49\times 10^{-3}T-3.223\times 10^{-6}T^2}{T} \cdot dT=\nu \alpha \cdot dP$

Now, we can integrate the left part fairly easy by dividing the $T$ into the expression and integrating term-by-term.

If $\nu$ and $\alpha$ are not constants, then you'd need to find a relationship between them and either $P$, or $T$. Then you'd need to rearrange accordingly. Hopefully it is still separable after establishing the relationship. (I.e. $\nu ≠(P+kT)$ and the like)

Once you've determined the nature of $\nu$ and $\alpha$ with respect to pressure and temperature, then you can solve $P$ in terms of $T$ and find the answer.